# Oracle SQL or PL/SQL correlated update column values Y/N

Tags: oracle, sql-update

Am trying to update single column with multiple values (Y/N) by correlated update and getting error  could use:

> ORA-01427: single-row sub-query returns more than one row.

I have two tables.

**REQUESTS_TABLE**

```
+-------------+------+
| CUSTOMER_ID | FLAG |
+-------------+------+
|         200 |      |
|         900 |      |
+-------------+------+
```

**CREDITS_TABLE**

```
+-------------+---------------+
| CUSTOMER_ID | CUSTOMER_NAME |
+-------------+---------------+
|         100 | John          |
|         200 | Smith         |
|         300 | Mary          |
|         400 | David         |
|         500 | Jake          |
+-------------+---------------+
```

If customer_id from requests table exists in credits table then I want to update "FLAG" column in requests table as 'Y'. If not found then 'N'. Below is the output am trying to get:

**OUTPUT :**
**REQUESTS_TABLE**

```
+-------------+------------+
| CUSTOMER_ID | FOUND_FLAG |
+-------------+------------+
|         200 | Y          |
|         900 | N          |
+-------------+------------+
```

Below is the query that I tried which is resulting in error:

```
UPDATE requests_table r 
SET    ( flag ) = (SELECT CASE 
                            WHEN c.customer_id IS NOT NULL THEN 'Y' 
                            ELSE 'N' 
                          END 
                   FROM   credits_table c 
                   WHERE  c.customer_id = r.customer_id) 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM   credits_table c 
               WHERE  c.customer_id = r.customer_id)
```

When I searched online for the help I found queries that updates multiple columns but not multiple values in single column. Hence seeking help here.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks,
Richa

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use:

```
UPDATE requests_table
SET found_flag = CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT c.customer_id FROM credits_table c 
                                 WHERE c.customer_id = requests_table.customer_id)
                      THEN 'Y'
                      ELSE 'N'
                 END
```

Comment: Hi @Lukasz Szozda, thanks for quick response. Query worked like a charm. I appreciate your help. I would like to inform that it took almost 10 minutes to update the rows. Table had nearly 85k rows. Is there a way to improve the performance? Am thinking to replace * with customer_id, will it increase the performance?

Comment: @Richa Adding index could help`CREATE INDEX r_idx ON requests_table(customer_id)` and `CREATE INDEX c_idx ON credits_table(customer_id)`.

Comment: Creating index on both tables on column customer_id did increase performance. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off doing this as two statements (ideally in a single transaction):

```
UPDATE requests_table
SET    found_flag = 'N';

UPDATE requests_table
SET    found_flag = 'Y'
WHERE  EXISTS
           (SELECT *
            FROM   credits_table c
            WHERE  c.customer_id = requests_table.customer_id);
```

This is likely to perform better than @LukaszSzozda's answer, as it avoids the nested sub-query which would need to be run for every row in the `requests_table`.

---

Another option for doing this in a single query, which should be of a comparable speed is to use `merge` (I tend to use `merge` over `update` for all but the simplest updates).

```
MERGE INTO requests_table
USING      (SELECT rt.customer_id,
                   CASE WHEN c.customer_id IS NULL THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END
                       AS found_flag
            FROM   requests_table rt
                   LEFT JOIN credits_table c
                       ON c.customer_id = rt.customer_id) src
ON         (requests_table.customer_id = src.customer_id)
WHEN MATCHED THEN
    UPDATE SET found_flag = src.found_flag
```

Comment: This was superfast. Thanks @Allan

Comment: Hi @Allan, I tried query with merge statement but am getting following error: ORA-00904: "SRC"."FOUND_FLAG": invalid identifier

Comment: I left the alias out of the inner query. It's been updated.

Comment: wow awesome. Thank you so much @Allan. I highly appreciate your help and superfast response.